# How to link static .a library with gradle to android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I'm trying to link separately built static library which has .a format to my android project using gradle.

Is there any way to do it without using gradle-experimental plugin ?

Comment: suggest a review of : http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/

Comment: there is nothing about static linking in that post, I know how to use .so shared libraries but not .a static libs